# Run Process and Don't Wait

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I'd like to run a process and not wait for it to return.  I've tried spawn with P_NOWAIT and subprocess like this:

```
app = "C:\Windows\Notepad.exe"
file = "C:\Path\To\File.txt"

pid = subprocess.Popen(
    [app, file], 
    shell=True, 
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
).pid
```

However, the console window remains until I close Notepad.  Is it possible to launch the process and not wait for it to complete?

Comment: Are you using `python.exe` or `pythonw.exe`?

Comment: Apparently python is smart enough to realize those backslashes aren't escape characters, nevertheless, I would avoid doing that by using `r'C:\path'` or even better `'C:/path'`

Comment: @NickT or just single quote instead of double

Comment: @aking1012 single vs. double quoted strings are parsed differently?  Did not know

Comment: @NickT - I could be mistaken and it's a holdover from other languages.  In some languages single quotes don't do as much expansion/interpretation of what's inside the quotes.

Comment: @aking1012: You are; Python does not treat single and double quotes differently.

Comment: See also [Can subprocess.call be invoked without waiting for process to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965949/can-subprocess-call-be-invoked-without-waiting-for-process-to-finish)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This call doesn't wait for the child process to terminate (on Linux). Don't ask me what `close_fds` does; I wrote the code some years ago. (BTW: The documentation of `subprocess.Popen` is confusing, IMHO.)

```
proc = Popen([cmd_str], shell=True,
             stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
```

**Edit:**

I looked at the the documentation of [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html), and I believe the important aspect for you is `stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None,`. Otherwise *Popen* captures the program's output, and you are expected to look at it. `close_fds` makes the parent process' file handles inaccessible for the child.

Comment: I need the win32 DETACHED_PROCESS flag otherwise it hangs on Windows for me.

Comment: According to [1] shell=True may be a security hazard and if shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a String (I had problems with incorrectly passed args using a sequence and shell=True. Although my args sequence matched shlex output). I'm pretty sure shell=True is not needed for detaching (tested only on Linux).

Comment: Since most of the answer's args are their defaults, this can probably be simplified to `proc = Popen([cmd_str])` (notepad probably doesn't need `shell`).

Answer (score 32):

I finally got this to work. I'm running "Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:13:38) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] win32". Here's how I had to code it:

```
from subprocess import Popen
DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008
cmd = [
    sys.executable,
    'c:\somepath\someprogram.exe',
    parm1,
    parm2,
    parm3,
]
p = Popen(
    cmd, shell=False, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None,
    close_fds=True, creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS,
)
```

This turns off all piping of standard input/output and does NOT execute the called program in the shell. Setting 'creationflags' to DETACHED_PROCESS seemed to do the trick for me. I forget where I found out about it, but an example is used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970045/python-launch-a-long-running-process-from-a-web-app).

Comment: the proper way to tokenize is with shlex

Comment: creationflags is windows only

Answer (score 5):

I think the simplest way to implement this is using the [os.spawn*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=spawn#os.spawnl) family of functions passing the `P_NOWAIT` flag.

This for example will spawn a `cp` process to copy a large file to a new directory and not bother to wait for it.

```
import os
os.spawnlp(os.P_NOWAIT, 'cp', 'cp', '/path/large-file.db', '/path/dest')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are capturing input and output to the program so your program will not terminate as long as it keeps those file descriptors open. If you want to capture, you need to close the file descriptors. If you don't want to capture:

```
app = "C:\Windows\Notepad.exe"
file = "C:\Path\To\File.txt"

pid = subprocess.Popen([app, file]).pid
```