# Can subprocess.call be invoked without waiting for process to finish?

Tags: python

I'm currently using subprocess.call() to invoke another program, but it blocks the executing thread until that program finishes. Is there a way to simply launch that program without waiting for return?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Process and Don't Wait](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516007/run-process-and-dont-wait)

Comment: [Run Process and Don't Wait](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516007/run-process-and-dont-wait) is windows specific.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use `subprocess.Popen` instead of `subprocess.call`:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['foo', '-b', 'bar'])
```

`subprocess.call` is a wrapper around `subprocess.Popen` that calls [`communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to wait for the process to terminate. See also [What is the difference between subprocess.popen and subprocess.run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187886/what-is-the-difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-subprocess-run).

Comment: Is this answer supposed to be "no"? This answer does not really answer the question because sometimes you can not simply replace `subprocess.call` by `subprocess.popen`

Comment: @anion: Correct, the answer is no because the point of `call` is to wait for the process to terminate.

Comment: How would I not wait but retain the ability to capture the output of the process and retain a handle to the process so I can kill it if necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the answer be to use 'close_fds' flag?

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=None, stderr=None, stdin=None, close_fds=True)
```

Comment: The explicit argument is not needed, because [`close_fds=True` is default for `Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=close_fds#subprocess.Popen)