# Python to call another python without waiting for it to complete using os or subprocess

Tags: python, python-os

I have a python script. Which is running as a service with a while loop for ever. The script need to be executed by another python but without waiting for the out put it should pass through.

So the main script with while loop is as follows "main.py". Which never going to be end.

```
while True:
    # do some task
    time.sleep(5)
```

This need to be executed by another python "start.py" with similar function as follows.

```
os.system("main.py 1")
```

OR

subprocess.Popen("python main.py")

Problem here "start.py" won't finish as witing for the out put of "main.py". But I want to make it like "start.py" need to load "main.py" and leave it in background. Then the "start.py" need to complete the process. How can I modify the

> os.system("main.py 1")

function to skip the waiting for "main.py"? Please consider this need to run on cross platform.

Comment: why not use `subprocess.Popen`? os.system is going to wait for the process to  return, Popen won't,  you could also use `&` to background the process

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516007/run-process-and-dont-wait

Comment: subprocess.Popen is fine. But still it keeping the console with the next script execute.

Comment: Isn't using & to background just a shell feature? Which won't for windows.

Comment: @sugunan, `subprocess.Popen("python main.py")` would not run, it would also won't wait for `main.py` to finish

Comment: Will the threading support te background process.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend for you to check out Plumbum https://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ specifically the section on background/foreground https://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#foreground-and-background-execution

```
from plumbum import BG
from plumbum.cmd import python

python('main.py', '1') & BG
```

Cross platform also.

Comment: No Module named plumbum error come.

Comment: have you installed it?