# How to detach a program ran by subprocess.call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am opening a pdf file with my default application using subprocess.call, like this:

```
subprocess.call(["xdg-open", pdf], stderr=STDOUT)
```

But, when running that, the process is attached to the terminal and I want to detach it. Basically, I want to run that and then be able to use the terminal for other stuff.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516007/run-process-and-dont-wait

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) for this.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
p = Popen(["xdg-open", pdf], stderr=STDOUT, stdout=PIPE)
# do your own thing while xdg-open runs as a child process
output, _ = p.communicate()
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to do what I want. It does not detach from terminal. Doing stdout=subprocess.PIPE does detach from terminal, but it opens in the browser and not in the pdf-viewer.

Comment: Doing pdf = Popen(["xdg-open", pdf], stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True, shell=False) fixed my problem.