# Playbook 'hangs' when running a Python script that launches another Windows process

Tags: ansible

I'm having an issue when running a Python script using the `win_command` module. The playbook execution hangs indefinitely when the Python script starts a Tomcat process which is supposed to keep running even once the script completes. If I were to manually kill the Tomcat process, the Ansible playbook completes.

```yaml
---
- name: Restore product
  win_command: 'python restore-product.py'
  args:
    chdir: C:\temp
```

I have tried the following within the Python script hoping that Ansible would not be able to track the launched process, but have had no luck:

```py
subprocess.Popen('start /cmd /c service.bat startup', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: What happens when you manually runs this piece of Python from a Windows host? Does it correctly gives you back the prompt or does it also hangs indefinitely, as does your playbook?

Comment: If I run the Python script from the Windows host it will exit at sys.exit(0) and return back to a command prompt.

Comment: I'd bet the problem is that the process is still attached to the current terminal . So the python script is done but the terminal still has a running process attached to stdin/out/err and ansible task does not exit. Can you try with something like `subprocess.Popen('start /cmd /c service.bat startup', stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True, shell=False)`? (see comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51538651/how-to-detach-a-program-ran-by-subprocess-call)). Study Popen doc for more options to try.

Comment: Friendly note: running Tomcat as a service would probably ease your life a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions @Zeitounator!  I will give that a try.  You are correct about running Tomcat as a service as when I tried this before Ansible works fine except I need to run Tomcat as a command line service to workaround another issue (which is a long story :) ).

I will update the post after I tried the Python changes

Comment: I suggest you give some background about this "other long story issue" because you might very well be in an [x/y problem](https://xyproblem.info) here and I'm almost sure some windows experts (i.e. not me;)) know how to fix that inside a running service.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Python's popen function and rather go for spawn() as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1196122/4222206

Comment: I tried the following on Windows: 
`os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT, sys.executable, 'C:\tomcat\bin\service.bat startup')` which returns a process ID of '0' without the process being started.  Are I missing something?