# Start background process in python via subprocess and write output to file

Tags: python, subprocess

Dear stackoverflow users,

I'm looking for a solution for a probably quite easy problem. I want to automate some quantum chemical calculations and ran into a small problem.

Normally you start your quantum chemical programm (in my case it's called orca) with your input file (*.inp) on a remote server as a background process and pipe the output into an outputfile (*.out) via

```
nohup orca H2.inp >& H2.out &
```

or something similar.

Now I wanted to use a python script (with some templating) to write the input file automatically. At the end the script should start the calculation in a way that I could log out of the server without stopping orca. I tried that with

```
subprocess.run(["orca", input_file], stdout=output_file)
```

but so far it did not work. How do I "emulate" the command given at the top with the subprocess module?

Regards

**Update**
I have one file that is called `H2.xyz`. The script reads and splits the filename by the point and creates an input file name `H2.inp` and the output should be written into the file `H2.out`.

**Update 2**
The input file is derived from the *xyz file via

```
xyzfile = str(sys.argv[1])
input_file = xyzfile.split(".")[0] + ".inp"
output_file = xyzfile.split(".")[0] + ".out"
```

and is created within the script via templating. In the end I want to run the script in the following way:

```
python3 script.py H2_0_1.xyz
```

Comment: try ``subprocess.run`` with ``shell = True``.

Comment: "If the shell is invoked explicitly, via shell=True, it is the application’s responsibility to ensure that all whitespace and metacharacters are quoted appropriately to avoid shell injection vulnerabilities" from https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations

Comment: is `output_file` the path to a file (I don't think that will work) or a file-like object (like what you get from using the `open(output_file, 'w')` method?

Comment: So far I did not get it to work, so I'm open to any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
subprocess.Popen(f'orca {input_file} >& {output_file}',
                 shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
```

More info:
[Run Process and Don't Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516007/run-process-and-dont-wait)

Comment: like I commented in the question shell=True is not secure, because of injection vulnerabilities. In my solution Python is taking care of that. But yes I might be over killing it xDDD

Answer (score 1):

For me (Windows, Python 2.7) the method `call` works very fine like this:

```
with open('H2.out', 'a') as out :
    subprocess.call(['orca', infile], stdout=out,
                                      stderr=out,
                                      shell=True)   # Yes, I know. But It's Windows.
```

---

On Linux you maybe do not need `shell=True` for a list of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem not long ago.
Here is my solution:

```
commandLineCode = "nohup orca H2.inp >& H2.out &"
try:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(commandLineCode,
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                            cwd = workingDir)

except OSError:
    print("Windows Error occured")
    print(traceback.format_exc())

timeoutInSeconds = 100
try:
    outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout = timeoutInSeconds)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    print("timeout")
    proc.kill()
    outs, errs = proc.communicate()

stdoutDecode = outs.decode("utf-8")
stderrDecode = errs.decode("utf-8")

for line in stdoutDecode.splitlines():
    # write line to outputFile
if stderrDecode:
    for line in stderrDecode.splitlines():
        # write line to error log
```

The OSError exception is pretty important since you never now what your OS might do wrong.

For more on the communicate() command which actually starts the process read: 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Answer (score 0):

Is the usage of subprocess important? If not, you could use [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system).

The Python call would get really short, in your case

```
os.system("nohup orca H2.inp >& H2.out &")
```

should do the trick.