# What is the easiest way to launch a Python file from another Python file then send data across them while they run simultaneously?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, io, subprocess

I want to first run a python file(parent) which automatically executes another python file(child) and send data(specifically a list) from the parent file to the child file.

I cannot import one file into another since the parent file has to execute a lot of blocking commands and I need the child file to publish continuously.

I initially tried Popen subprocess with which I was able to run both at the same time but I wasn't able to catch any output from the parent in the child class. Simply writing data to a file then reading it from the child class could work but I wasn't able to get it working reliably since it only read once; and closing the file to open it again to read seemed way too hacky and slow.

So how is this normally done? Here's a super-simplified version of the code:-

File 1(Parent file):-

```
list = [0,0,0]
class CmdDecide:
    def __init__(self, param1=50):
        //Some code
        //I tried subprocess.run(['python3',file2.py]) to run the 2 files simultaneously but I need to send the list variable to it
    
    def func_A(self, var_from_someplace_else):
        global list
        list = var_from_someplace_else
        sendList(list)
    
    def sendList(self):
        //Code to send this list to file 2 somehow
    
    //There are a lot more functions in this file
```

File 2(Child file):-

```
def main():
    //Send continuous output [0,0,0] till File 1 changes the array
    //It will continuously output the new array and continue to do so till the program is terminated
```

Note: Ik this exists [Run one Python code in the background from another Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55071274/run-one-python-code-in-the-background-from-another-python-code) but the pipe has not been implemented and I'm not sure if it can even handle lists.

Answer (score 0):

If the main concern of merging the two files into one is blocking processes then run the parent file methods as *async* (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). Invoking one file as a sub-process is not in my opinion the best way to go forwards as it decouples the logic but maintains the dependency.
If you need to invoke the file as a sub-process then look into *argpase* and pass the list as a argument to

`subprocess.run(['python3',file2.py])`