# How to detect which windows desktop I'm on in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-10, desktop

In Windows 10 you can create multiple desktops and switch between them.
I want to run a python3 code when I am on a certain desktop.
How do I detect which desktop I'm on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764356/python-get-windows-os-version-and-architecture

Comment: @ΕυάγγελοςΓρηγορόπουλος, how does that help OP with their question about the current [Windows desktop](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/multiple-desktops-in-windows-10-36f52e38-5b4a-557b-2ff9-e1a60c976434)?

Comment: I'm not on Windows, but see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60938828/9059420) and the linked `VirtualDesktopAccessor.dll`. Then it's probably `GetCurrentDesktopNumber()` what you need to call from that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the VirtualDesktopAccessor.dll from [here](https://github.com/Ciantic/VirtualDesktopAccessor/raw/master/x64/Release/VirtualDesktopAccessor.dll) and put it in your working directory.

Run the following code:

```
import ctypes

vda = ctypes.WinDLL("VirtualDesktopAccessor.dll")
num = vda.GetCurrentDesktopNumber()
print(num)
```