# Invoking Jar from Python script causes Script to halt

Tags: python

I am using `langugagetool.jar` in my Python script to check for spelling and grammatical errors. Before the main logic of the script starts, I am executing this call ensure that the language tool server is running:

```
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'languagetool.jar'], shell=True)
```

This opens up the language tool GUI window and the prevents the Python script from executing further logic as the control transfers to the GUI window. How can I return control to Python script after language tool window opens?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516007/run-process-and-dont-wait

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Process and Don't Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516007/run-process-and-dont-wait)