# How to start daemon process from python on windows?

Tags: python, windows, daemon

Can my python script spawn a process that will run indefinitely?

I'm not too familiar with python, nor with spawning deamons, so I cam up with this:

```
si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
si.dwFlags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
subprocess.Popen(executable, close_fds = True, startupinfo = si)
```

The process continues to run past python.exe, but is closed as soon as I close the cmd window.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2974177/222914

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970045/python-launch-a-long-running-process-from-a-web-app/2974177#2974177) Janne Karila pointed out this is how you can run a process that doen't die when its parent dies, no need to use the `win32process` module.

```
DETACHED_PROCESS = 8
subprocess.Popen(executable, creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS, close_fds=True)
```

`DETACHED_PROCESS` is a [Process Creation Flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx) that is passed to the underlying [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Comment: Where did you get DETACHED_PROCESS from? It does not look like one of the subprocess constants: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#constants

Comment: I found the `DETACHED_PROCESS` in [python 3.7 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) - you can use `subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS`

Answer (score 18):

This question was asked 3 years ago, and though the fundamental details of the answer haven't changed, given its prevalence in "Windows Python daemon" searches, I thought it might be helpful to add some discussion for the benefit of future Google arrivees.

There are really two parts to the question:

1. Can a Python script spawn an independent process that will run indefinitely?
2. Can a Python script act like a Unix daemon on a Windows system?

The answer to the first is an unambiguous yes; as already pointed out; using `subprocess.Popen` with the `creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` keyword will suffice:

```
import subprocess

independent_process = subprocess.Popen(
    'python /path/to/file.py',
    creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP
)
```

Note that, at least in my experience, `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` is not necessary here.

That being said, the behavior of this strategy isn't quite the same as what you'd expect from a Unix daemon. What constitutes a well-behaved Unix daemon is [better explained elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515165/correct-daemon-behaviour-from-pep-3143-explained), but to summarize:

1. Close open file descriptors (typically all of them, but some applications may need to protect some descriptors from closure)
2. Change the working directory for the process to a suitable location to prevent "Directory Busy" errors
3. Change the file access creation mask (`os.umask` in the Python world)
4. Move the application into the background and make it dissociate itself from the initiating process
5. Completely divorce from the terminal, including redirecting `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, and `STDERR` to different streams (often `DEVNULL`), and prevent reacquisition of a controlling terminal
6. Handle signals, in particular, `SIGTERM`.

The reality of the situation is that Windows, as an operating system, really doesn't support the notion of a daemon: applications that start from a terminal (or in any other interactive context, including launching from Explorer, etc) will continue to run with a visible window, unless the controlling application (in this example, Python) has included a windowless GUI. Furthermore, Windows signal handling is woefully inadequate, and attempts to send signals to an *independent* Python process (as opposed to a subprocess, which would not survive terminal closure) will almost always result in the immediate exit of that Python process **without any cleanup** (no `finally:`, no `atexit`, no `__del__`, etc).

Rolling your application into a Windows service, though a viable alternative in many cases, also doesn't quite fit. The same is true of using `pythonw.exe` (a [windowless version of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30313091/5964816) that ships with all recent Windows Python binaries). In particular, they fail to improve the situation for signal handling, and they cannot easily launch an application from a terminal and interact with it during startup (for example, to deliver dynamic startup arguments to your script, say, perhaps, a password, file path, etc), **before** "daemonizing". Additionally, Windows services require installation, which -- though perfectly possible to do quickly at runtime when you first call up your "daemon" -- modifies the user's system (registry, etc), which would be highly unexpected if you're coming from a Unix world.

**In light of that, I would argue that launching a `pythonw.exe` subprocess using `subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` is probably the closest Windows equivalent for a Python process to emulate a traditional Unix daemon.** However, that still leaves you with the added challenge of signal handling and startup communications (not to mention making your code platform-dependent, which is always frustrating).

That all being said, for anyone encountering this problem in the future, I've rolled a library called [daemoniker](https://github.com/Muterra/py_daemoniker) that wraps both proper Unix daemonization *and* the above strategy. It also implements signal handling (for both Unix and Windows systems), and allows you to pass objects to the "daemon" process using pickle. Best of all, it has a [cross-platform API](https://daemoniker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```
from daemoniker import Daemonizer

with Daemonizer() as (is_setup, daemonizer):
    if is_setup:
        # This code is run before daemonization.
        do_things_here()

    # We need to explicitly pass resources to the daemon; other variables
    # may not be correct
    is_parent, my_arg1, my_arg2 = daemonizer(
        path_to_pid_file,
        my_arg1,
        my_arg2
    )

    if is_parent:
        # Run code in the parent after daemonization
        parent_only_code()

# We are now daemonized, and the parent just exited.
code_continues_here()
```

Comment: High Nick, going to give this a try to see if I can port a linux only script to be cross-platform dependent. Was previously using python-daemon, will report back how it goes!

Might be an idea to add a note at the top of your post mentioning your library so that people looking for the answer can see it more easily :)

Answer (score 6):

For that purpose you could daemonize your python process or as you are using windows environment you would like to run this as a windows service.

You know i like to hate posting only web-links:

But for more information according to your requirement:

[**A simple way to implement Windows Service**.](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/551780/) read all comments it will resolve any doubt

If you really want to learn more

First read this

what is daemon process or [creating-a-daemon-the-python-way](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/278731-creating-a-daemon-the-python-way/)

**update:**
Subprocess is not the right way to achieve this kind of thing

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want a service, in fact I can't use one because I'm told not to.

Comment: Glad to know, another answer's link work out for you. But for your information i wanted to give you complete feel how it is done, infect it you open suprocess.py( and start reading from line 599) you will it same as creating a daemon, But now i do think that popen is good for you.