# Is there a way for a python program to continue running even after it's closed (like automatic open at a certain time)?

Tags: python, windows, background

To be more specific: Is there a way for a python program to continue running even after it's closed (like automatic open at a certain time)? Or like a gmail notification? This is for an alarm project, and I want it to ring/open itself even if the user closes the window. Is there a way for this to happen/get scripted? If so, how? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like what you want is for the user to be able to close the window but keep the program running in the background

Comment: long-running background task, or execute for certain time interval ?

Comment: ian is correct and raptor's second guess i think is also correct (pls correct me if not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into daemon processes and cron jobs.

[How to start daemon process from python on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843903/how-to-start-daemon-process-from-python-on-windows)

[How do I get a Cron like scheduler in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/how-do-i-get-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. You just hide the window without destroying it. It will run for ever until you kill the mainloop itself. Your questing is too broad.