# Run a executable by python at background and still running

Tags: python-2.7

I have a executable made by `py2exe` which verifies whether my VPN is connected or not at infinite loop running on Windows. I want to make sure it runs in background or hidden, I searched for several forums and I found 2 scripts worked partially.

1. Rename script to `scrypt.py` and run `py2exe` again, the .exe hide when I run it, but close or vanish. Doesn't continue running after the click.
2. I am made another exe to call the first

```py
    import os
    import subprocess

    os.chdir("C:\Users\dl\Documents\Log\Py")
    proc = subprocess.Popen('ipLog.exe',  creationflags=subprocess.SW_HIDE, shell=True)
    proc.wait()
```

or

```py
    os.chdir("C:\Users\dl\Documents\Log\Py")
    proc = subprocess.Popen('ipLog.exe',  creationflags=subprocess.SW_HIDE, shell=True)
```

Works but the first command still visible, and when i close it, the first exe call by it quit too.

3. I tried install a module call self.hide but i cant.

I am newbie in python and try to change my hobbies vb, vba to python.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Then edit your question and format it properly.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in this thread [How to start daemon process from python on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843903/how-to-start-daemon-process-from-python-on-windows). Thank you all people helped with this thread, help my script too.