# How to start a daemon in python using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, daemons

I want to start a daemon process using multiprocessing exiting the main thread. I wrote this code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from time import sleep

def mytarget():
    while True:
        print "yes"
        sleep(1)

process = mp.Process(target=mytarget)
process.daemon = True
process.start()
```

But the daemon process doesn't appear. I know I can solve it using os.fork  like this:

```
import os
from time import sleep

def mytarget():
    while True:
        print "yes"
        sleep(1)

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    mytarget()
```

But it's not supported in Windows. So I need a solution for multiprocessing module. Thanks!

Comment: The multiprocessing module is not meant for this. Use a library for creating daemons or services. I can recommend the [`service` package](http://python-service.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start daemon process from python on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843903/how-to-start-daemon-process-from-python-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Looking through [PyPyi there are quite a few solutions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=daemon&submit=search), e.g.  [py_daemoniker](https://github.com/Muterra/py_daemoniker).