# prevent windows popingup when exe run from python

Tags: python, subprocess, exe

I’m using python to batch run a scientific application (DNDC) compiled for OS Windows using the `subprocess.run()` function:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(r'root_path_to_dndc/exe/console/DNDC95.exe -s path_to_input.txt -output path_to_output -root root_path_to_dndc')
```

DNDC occasionally pops up a window for some error messages that blocks the python code from continuing running until I manually click on the “OK” button to go onward. Is there any method to catch the error message then kill the process? This matters as I need to run the last code over a very large number of times (> 100k).

I have tried setting a `try, except` block in my code but the problem is that Python detects no error as DNDC .exe is launched sucessfully. I need therefore to figure out how to catch the error message windows that DNDC fires.

Details:

- The batch script is written whith Python 3.12.
- The batch script is run on a remote OS Unix server with the "wine" app.
- I have no admin rights on the server (cannot run Disable-WindowsErrorReporting)
- DNDC is a scientific application (for carbon cycle simulations), available from github (https://github.com/BrianBGrant/DNDCv.CAN/blob/master/DNDC_Jan2024.zip)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843903/how-to-start-daemon-process-from-python-on-windows

Comment: Thanks for your answer Raymond. If I understand well, this will allow the Python code to continue running. However, wouldn't such a workaround overload my system (with more than 1000000 runs to go)?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to find the error dialog's window name and periodically "evaluate the open windows" with that name from another process. If found, find its process using the window info and kill it (or SendKeys("\n")).

I know it can be done in Windows and I believe it should work under wine, too.

Comment: Thanks Orhan, I thought about this solution but still, I would finish by doing so but this still is a workaround. I would first exlore solutions that would allow intercepting the messages so that I would not have to run periodic scripts.